# Android : Toolbar is not getting displayed in two pane layout for tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i have a two pane layout in my app but content of tool bar is not getting displayed properly.
In left pane shows share button and play button instead of this it should be shown in right pane
when i click on left pane item then share menu and play menu is shown in both pane and 
when i change list item of left pane using navigation drawer then title of left pane is not getting changed

This is the snapshot of my Project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `android:fitsSystemWindows` property in your `CoordinatorLayout` or `ToolBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the two layouts (the left and right pane) inside another parent layout and before them set the toolbar.

Please try posting the XML code of your current layout.